# Javascript not executing (I included format.js)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I added format.js to my controller, yet I still cannot get the js in index.js.erb to execute when I view my index page.  The only thing I can figure out is that it must be because of the model name.  I had to add

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'business', 'businesses'
end
```

to my inflections.rb file...because my model is called Business.

my views/js are located at views/businesses/*

Please help before I pull my hair out!

All I have in the index.js.erb file is:

```
alert(1);
```

Obviously the goal is that I will get an alert when I finally get the issue fixed, letting me know it is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you calling your index page? If you visit the index page from your your browser it won't render `index.js`. That's the whole point behind using format. You will have to call your index method using javascript(something like an ajax call). Your model name does not have anything to do with it.

Comment: Ok, well...whenever you access a page routed to /model/index it should execute /app/views/pluralized-model/index.js.erb after the page loads...the same with the other actions like edit (then execution of /app/views/pluralized-model/edit.js.erb should happen).  The problem is, this is not happening.

Comment: Its not like that. You are getting the concept wrong. respond_to block renders proper output based on the format of request. So if you call app_name/clients/1/edit it will execute format.html and when you call app_name/clients/1/edit.js it will  execute format.js block.

Comment: Oh ya, I did know that before...that still doesn't explain why the edit.js.erb file does not execute when the edit action is called.  I know for a fact it is supposed to because I have 2 other websites up and running right now where I did just that.

Comment: @SuperEngineer is correct, Rails does not work like that. I'm not sure what you did in your two websites that are up and running, but this is not how Rails works out of the box.You would have to use document ready and make an ajax call to edit.js.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript execution has nothing to do with your model names. Nor is the inclusion of your JS files done based on the name of the controller or model. If you are using the asset pipeline you need the following.

Assuming that index.js is in /assets/javascripts/index.js, add the following to the /app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require ./index
```

If you don't understand how this works, you may wish to go through the Ruby on Rails Guide for the Asset Pipeline, found here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

As a side note, with your inflections usage, I would recommend that if you are going to use a framework like Rails, try and use conventions that come with it. It will save you heartache in future. Name your model business so that your table is called businesses. Unless you really want something like this:

```
has_one :businesses
```

Comment: Read my post again, my model is not called Businesses, it is called Business.  I had to implement custom inflection because rails has a known issue with words that end in 's' in their singular form.  As far as file location, the js file is /app/views/businesses/index.js.erb which should execute when I browse the url that is routed to businesses#index.  It is not executing though.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question. If you want a JS action to fire after the HTML action fires, you will have to embed JS in your HTML to request the JS once the HTML is loaded.